# several loops over a single list in a list comprehension

Tags: python

I have the data that looks like this

```
[
    'GET ... \n GET ...',
    'POST ...',
    '<content>...</content>',
    'GET ...'
]
```

I want to turn this list into this one

```
[
    [ 'GET ...', 'GET...' ],
    [ 'POST ...' ],
    [ 'GET ...' ]
]
```

where I have filtered all non HTTP requests elements and split the lines of multiline strings.

I do it like this

```
strings = [
  'GET ... \r\n GET...',
  'POST ...' ,
  'GET ...'
]
def normalize_text(txt, to_lower=True):
    if txt is not None:
        strp = txt.strip()
        if to_lower:
            return strp.lower()
        return strp
    return txt

for string in strings:
  queries = [normalize_text(query) for query in string.splitlines()]
  true_queries = [query for query in queries if not query.startswith('<')]
  print(true_queries)
```

It works. But is there a way to combine two list comprehensions - one for splitting and another one for checking the string - into a single one?

Comment: I'm curious, where does that string come from?

Comment: some websites keep on the page `<pre>` tags containing multiple lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anything wrong with:

```
for string in strings:
    true_queries = [normalize_text(query) for for query in queries if not query.startswith('<')]
```

? Or, if you expect `<` might be preceded by some whitespace, then slightly less efficient but handling that case:

```
for string in strings:
    true_queries = [ true_query in (normalize_text(query) for query in queries) if not true_query.startswith('<') ]
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the text may contain additional spaces, or other symbols in before I get to the tag. Sad that Python doesn't like functional pipelines

Comment: So it will evaluate the list inside `()` only once?

Comment: Since it is a generator expression rather than list comprehension, no temporary list will be created. The expression in parentheses will return consecutive values as they are requested by the "outer" expression, in this case the list comprehension.